# Managing 100s of conflicts

Tags: git

3 Months ago, a created a branch `phase2` out of `master`. The `phase2` of project go developed in `phase2` branch in a couple of months. And in parallel, `master` was also in development and go so many new commits there. Now it's time to go live with `phase2`. I am trying to merge `phase2` in `master` by creating a pull request on BitBucket, but I get hundreds of conflicts in so many files. What could be best approach to handle this and go live with `phase2` by merging it into `master`?

Answer (score 2):

Merge (or *may be* rebase) `master` to `phase2` instead of vice versa.

Then resolve all the conflicts slowly and accurately. Test the build several times.
It can easily take more than one day, but what to do?

At last merge `phase2` to `master` fast and easy.

Comment: Why is rebase "better"?

Comment: It would be better to merge `master` TO `phase2` every day for 3 months.

Comment: Rebasing is a pain to do if there are non-trivial conflicts - you potentially have to resolve multiple commits.

Comment: I thought user3184235 commited to both `master` and `phase2`. And `master` wasn't a really public branch.